# How to autoscroll facebook page plugin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, facebook-page

This is the iframe where I want to implement the auto-scrolling feature.`<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpage_name%2F&tabs=timeline&width=500&height=500&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=true&show_facepile=true&appId=---" width="500" height="400" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>`

Comment: Please format code properly, use edit feature under question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="preview" onLoad="scrollToBottom()"></iframe>

function scrollToBottom() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

}

$('#preview').contents().scrollTop($('#preview').contents().height());
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but this solution is not working for Facebook page plugin iframe.